# Android ProgressBar not clearing after disabling its indeterminate feature

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I ran into a problem when switching between `ProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true)` and `ProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false)`.

In my code I call the following before starting a longer running task:

```
myv_BottomView.setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

which actually calls `setIndeterminate(true)` on a progress bar located inside my custom view (myv_BottomView).

All OK. The progress bar starts animating. After a while my long running task finishes and I call:

```
myv_BottomView.setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
myv_BottomView.setProgressBarValue(0);
```

which actually calls `setIndeterminate(false)` and `setProgress(0)` on a progress bar located inside my custom view (myv_BottomView).

The first line of code is successful. The progress bar stops animating and stops at some random position. But setting its progress to 0 doesn't work. So I can't "clear" the progress bar. If I replace `setIndeterminate(true)` with `setProgress(100)` and `setIndeterminate(false)` with `setProgress(0)` behaviour is as expected - progress bar is at 100% while my task is being executed and set back to 0 when it is finished. So setting the value appears to work.

Below is my full code.

Initializing the progressbar inside my custom view (myv_BottomView) constructor:

```
public Myview_BottomView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    //Initialize progress bar pb_LightIntensity
    my_ProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    my_ProgressBar.setId(ID_PB);
    final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };  // Define a shape with ...
    ShapeDrawable pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null));   // ... rounded corners
    gDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xFFf6a200);     // Sets the shape's (progress bar's) color
    ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);    // Adds the drawable to ...
    my_ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(progress); // ... our progressBar
    ShapeDrawable pgBackgroundDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null)); // Define another shape with rounded corners (used for background)
    pgBackgroundDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xFFa9a9a9);    // Sets the shape's (background's) color
    my_ProgressBar.setBackgroundDrawable(pgBackgroundDrawable);
    my_ProgressBar.setMax(100);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mylp_pbIntesity = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //mylp_pbIntesity.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, txtview_DeviceName.getId());
    mylp_pbIntesity.setMargins(
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 
            (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    my_ProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(progress);
    //Add views to base layout of this class (the class itself extends RelativeLayout)
    this.addView(my_ProgressBar, mylp_pbIntesity);
}
```

Setting progress value:

```
public void setProgressBarIndeterminate (boolean value) 
{ 
    if(my_ProgressBar!=null) {my_ProgressBar.setIndeterminate(value);} 
}
```

Setting indeterminate mode:

```
public void setProgressBarValue (int value) 
{
    if (my_ProgressBar != null) 
    { 
        try
        {
            if(my_ProgressBar.isIndeterminate() == false)
            {
                if(value>100) { my_ProgressBar.setProgress(100); }
                else { my_ProgressBar.setProgress(value); }
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Myview_BottomView.setProgressBarValue: Progress bar value set to " + my_ProgressBar.getProgress());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Myview_BottomView.setProgressBarValue: Progress bar not in determinate mode");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Myview_BottomView.setProgressBarValue: Exception updating progress bar value."); }
    }
}
```

So, my thinking is, that after calling setIndeterminate(false), setting progress bar values should again be made possible by calling setProgress(value). However this appears not to be the case. Can anyone offer any ideas as to why this is so in my case?

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe the indeterminate thing changes the max value? Did you try to `setMax(100)`?

Comment: @Michał K Sorry for the late reply. I tried that but it did not help. Since I did not find a solution quickly enough I just used the normal progressbar - without drawables. That works as expected and is in fact even better looking. :) Thanks anyway for your help.